# How to upload image from jimp with multer in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer, multer-gridfs-storage

I sent a request from the client with an image link in the body, in the node server I use jimp ([Jimp NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)) to resize the image which I was sent, then I need to save the image to mongodb with multer but I have some confuse with this step, does anyone have any idea ? thanks ! 
here is my code so far :

```
const multer = require('multer');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    exports.resizeImage = async function (req, res) {
        let storageFS = new GridFsStorage({
            db: app.get("mongodb"),
            file: (req, file) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return reject(err);
                        }
                        const filename =  file.originalname;
                        const fileInfo = {
                            filename: filename,
                            bucketName: 'images'
                        };
                        resolve(fileInfo);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        var upload = multer({ storage: storageFS }).single('image');
        try {
            Jimp.read(req.body.imagePath)        
            .then(image => {
                image.resize(150, 150, function (err, img) {
                    // How to store img to mongodb with multer here ? 
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                throw err
            });


        } catch (error) {
            res.send(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must add the `upload` generated by multer to a route in your express app. What you get is a middleware function that parses the request looking for files and fields but it doesn't work on its own.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Hi @ThierryTemplier
My solution is :
1. Resize image by jimp 
2. Upload to amazon s3 
3. Receive back image path 
4. Store this path in MongoDb
if you want example code, let's me know

Comment: hi @everyBit. Thanks very much for your answer. In fact, I'm trying to use the multer-s3 module but can't find how to do with jimp... I'm interested in having a sample ;-) thanks!

Comment: Hi @ThierryTemplier
here is my sample code https://ibb.co/D7FXYvT